# Embedding a Fusion TablesLayer Wizard Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-fusion-tables

Using the [Fusion LayersTable Wizard](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html) and a fusion table of my own, I get the following code (embedded at the end). It is supposed to be a map of Jalisco, with some kml data layer on top and a listbox that should act as a search/filter of the map. The wizard shows me a preview of waht my data and map should look like and in the preview everything works perfectly. But If I put the html code as the index.html file of my local web server, I can see the map, but the search listbox of the map doesn't work. Y dont know why is this happening I really need the search to work, but I just cant get it to work in my server.

I would really appreciate I someone can help my find whats wrong with the code, and help me get the search listbox working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <style>
       #map-canvas { width:900px; height:600px; }
     </style>
       <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
       </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var layerl0;
      function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.704738720055598, -103.64501953125),
      zoom: 8
    });
    var style = [
    {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'all',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit',
      elementType: 'all',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    }
  ];
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
    map: map,
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });
  map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
  layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'geometry'",
      from: '1UrfZ_tAPsMF9lUHkNWjQREsnbdRSMDKpHftF-rk'
    },
    map: map
  });
}
function changeMapl0() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'geometry'",
      from: 1UrfZ_tAPsMF9lUHkNWjQREsnbdRSMDKpHftF-rk,
      where: "'name' = '" + searchString + "'"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <label>Municipio</label>
  <select id="search-string-l0" onchange="changeMapl0(this.value);">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="TEOCUITATLAN DE CORONA (JAL)">TEOCUITATLAN DE CORONA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="UNION DE SAN ANTONIO (JAL)">UNION DE SAN ANTONIO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN DIEGO DE ALEJANDRIA (JAL)">SAN DIEGO DE ALEJANDRIA (JAL)     </option>
    <option value="GOMEZ FARIAS (JAL)">GOMEZ FARIAS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TONAYA (JAL)">TONAYA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TEQUILA (JAL)">TEQUILA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MANUEL M. DIEGUEZ (JAL)">MANUEL M. DIEGUEZ (JAL)</option>
    <option value="PUERTO VALLARTA (JAL)">PUERTO VALLARTA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CIUDAD GUZMAN (JAL)">CIUDAD GUZMAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="IXTLAHUACAN DEL RIO (JAL)">IXTLAHUACAN DEL RIO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SANTA MARIA DE LOS ANGELES (JAL)">SANTA MARIA DE LOS ANGELES (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TLAJOMULCO DE ZU¾IGA (JAL)">TLAJOMULCO DE ZU¾IGA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CABO CORRIENTES (JAL)">CABO CORRIENTES (JAL)</option>
    <option value="PONCITLAN (JAL)">PONCITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VILLA PURIFICACION (JAL)">VILLA PURIFICACION (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VALLE DE JUAREZ (JAL)">VALLE DE JUAREZ (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JOCOTEPEC (JAL)">JOCOTEPEC (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MANZANILLA DE LA PAZ, LA (JAL)">MANZANILLA DE LA PAZ, LA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JILOTLAN DE LOS DOLORES (JAL)">JILOTLAN DE LOS DOLORES (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CA¾ADAS DE OBREGON (JAL)">CA¾ADAS DE OBREGON (JAL)</option>
    <option value="GRULLO, EL (JAL)">GRULLO, EL (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN CRISTOBAL DE LA BARRANCA (JAL)">SAN CRISTOBAL DE LA BARRANCA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TOLIMAN (JAL)">TOLIMAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CUQUIO (JAL)">CUQUIO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MEZQUITIC (JAL)">MEZQUITIC (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AUTLAN DE NAVARRO (JAL)">AUTLAN DE NAVARRO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="HOSTOTIPAQUILLO (JAL)">HOSTOTIPAQUILLO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="UNION DE TULA (JAL)">UNION DE TULA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CONCEPCION DE BUENOS AIRES (JAL)">CONCEPCION DE BUENOS AIRES (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN MIGUEL EL ALTO (JAL)">SAN MIGUEL EL ALTO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SALTO, EL (JAL)">SALTO, EL (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JUANACATLAN (JAL)">JUANACATLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JUCHITLAN (JAL)">JUCHITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CIHUATLAN (JAL)">CIHUATLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ANTONIO ESCOBEDO (JAL)">ANTONIO ESCOBEDO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="DEGOLLADO (JAL)">DEGOLLADO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="LIMON, EL (JAL)">LIMON, EL (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VILLA GUERRERO (JAL)">VILLA GUERRERO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TECHALUTA DE MONTENEGRO (JAL)">TECHALUTA DE MONTENEGRO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZAPOTLANEJO (JAL)">ZAPOTLANEJO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MASCOTA (JAL)">MASCOTA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ARANDAS (JAL)">ARANDAS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TECOLOTLAN (JAL)">TECOLOTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="HUEJUCAR (JAL)">HUEJUCAR (JAL)</option>
    <option value="COLOTLAN (JAL)">COLOTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JALOSTOTITLAN (JAL)">JALOSTOTITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CUAUTITLAN (JAL)">CUAUTITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZACOALCO DE TORRES (JAL)">ZACOALCO DE TORRES (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JESUS MARIA (JAL)">JESUS MARIA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN MARTIN DE BOLA¾OS (JAL)">SAN MARTIN DE BOLA¾OS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TENAMAXTLAN (JAL)">TENAMAXTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TOMATLAN (JAL)">TOMATLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VILLA CORONA (JAL)">VILLA CORONA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="OJUELOS DE JALISCO (JAL)">OJUELOS DE JALISCO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="YAHUALICA DE GONZALEZ GALLO (JAL)">YAHUALICA DE GONZALEZ GALLO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CHAPALA (JAL)">CHAPALA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TECALITLAN (JAL)">TECALITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAYULA (JAL)">SAYULA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VALLE DE GUADALUPE (JAL)">VALLE DE GUADALUPE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CASIMIRO CASTILLO (JAL)">CASIMIRO CASTILLO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN MARTIN HIDALGO (JAL)">SAN MARTIN HIDALGO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZAPOTLAN DEL REY (JAL)">ZAPOTLAN DEL REY (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ARENAL (JAL)">ARENAL (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MEXTICACAN (JAL)">MEXTICACAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AYOTLAN (JAL)">AYOTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TAPALPA (JAL)">TAPALPA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TUXCUECA (JAL)">TUXCUECA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="COCULA (JAL)">COCULA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AHUALULCO DE MERCADO (JAL)">AHUALULCO DE MERCADO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MAZAMITLA (JAL)">MAZAMITLA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="IXTLAHUACAN DE LOS MEMBRILLOS (JAL)">IXTLAHUACAN DE LOS MEMBRILLOS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CHIQUILISTLAN (JAL)">CHIQUILISTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TEPATITLAN DE MORELOS (JAL)">TEPATITLAN DE MORELOS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CHIMALTITAN (JAL)">CHIMALTITAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN MARCOS (JAL)">SAN MARCOS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN JUAN DE LOS LAGOS (JAL)">SAN JUAN DE LOS LAGOS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="QUITUPAN (JAL)">QUITUPAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TLAQUEPAQUE (JAL)">TLAQUEPAQUE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="JAMAY (JAL)">JAMAY (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CUAUTLA (JAL)">CUAUTLA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="CIUDAD VENUSTIANO CARRANZA (JAL)">CIUDAD VENUSTIANO CARRANZA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ETZATLAN (JAL)">ETZATLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TOTATACHE (JAL)">TOTATACHE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AMECA (JAL)">AMECA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="OCOTLAN (JAL)">OCOTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MAGDALENA (JAL)">MAGDALENA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TEUCHITLAN (JAL)">TEUCHITLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="EJUTLA (JAL)">EJUTLA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ATENGUILLO (JAL)">ATENGUILLO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZAPOTITLAN DE VADILLO (JAL)">ZAPOTITLAN DE VADILLO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TEOCALTICHE (JAL)">TEOCALTICHE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN JULIAN (JAL)">SAN JULIAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TONALA (JAL)">TONALA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZAPOTILTIC (JAL)">ZAPOTILTIC (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ATENGO (JAL)">ATENGO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ATOYAC (JAL)">ATOYAC (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ZAPOPAN (JAL)">ZAPOPAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="PIHUAMO (JAL)">PIHUAMO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="HUEJUQUILLA EL ALTO (JAL)">HUEJUQUILLA EL ALTO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TUXCACUESCO (JAL)">TUXCACUESCO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="BARCA, LA (JAL)">BARCA, LA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="GUACHINANGO (JAL)">GUACHINANGO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TOTOTLAN (JAL)">TOTOTLAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ENCARNACION DE DIAZ (JAL)">ENCARNACION DE DIAZ (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AMACUECA (JAL)">AMACUECA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ACATLAN DE JUAREZ (JAL)">ACATLAN DE JUAREZ (JAL)</option>
    <option value="VILLA HIDALGO (JAL)">VILLA HIDALGO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ATOTONILCO EL ALTO (JAL)">ATOTONILCO EL ALTO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AYUTLA (JAL)">AYUTLA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ACATIC (JAL)">ACATIC (JAL)</option>
    <option value="SAN SEBASTIAN DEL OESTE (JAL)">SAN SEBASTIAN DEL OESTE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="LAGOS DE MORENO (JAL)">LAGOS DE MORENO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TONILA (JAL)">TONILA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="AMATITAN (JAL)">AMATITAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TALA (JAL)">TALA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="HUERTA, LA (JAL)">HUERTA, LA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TUXPAN (JAL)">TUXPAN (JAL)</option>
    <option value="BOLAôOS (JAL)">BOLAôOS (JAL)</option>
    <option value="GUADALAJARA (JAL)">GUADALAJARA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="ATEMAJAC DE BRIZUELA (JAL)">ATEMAJAC DE BRIZUELA (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TIZAPAN EL ALTO (JAL)">TIZAPAN EL ALTO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TALPA DE ALLENDE (JAL)">TALPA DE ALLENDE (JAL)</option>
    <option value="TAMAZULA DE GORDIANO (JAL)">TAMAZULA DE GORDIANO (JAL)</option>
    <option value="MIXTLAN (JAL)">MIXTLAN (JAL)</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your javascript errors?
If I copy your html page, I get this javascript error:

Message: Expected '}'
Line: 53
Char: 14
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/Larry/Documents/geocodezip/website/v3_FusionTables_WizOut.html

If I change this:
      from: 1UrfZ_tAPsMF9lUHkNWjQREsnbdRSMDKpHftF-rk,
To:
      from: "1UrfZ_tAPsMF9lUHkNWjQREsnbdRSMDKpHftF-rk",

I see a map.